# Slow UDP streaming on c linux inside windows but fast on apple?

Tags: c, linux, video, udp, wifi

i am working on a live video stream over wifi project.

we use UDP to send datagrams with the `sendto()` function using the `socket.h` file.

each datagram is 1420 bytes and those are being sent constantly with 250 uS delay between each.

now,
while sending the data from ubuntu (over windows) to an iPad, from some reason the `sendto()` function is being stalled and the stream is slow and unstable (i get a stream rate of about 1.28mb/sec).
this phenomena is only happen when the iPad is connected to the network, if it is not connected we get a flow rate of about 4mb/sec.
it is strange to me since i was under the impression that UDP protocol will keep on going and won't be affected by the receiver side.
now to get things even more strange, when i run the same code on a iMac using the terminal i get an amzing stream rate with perfect video on the other side....

router is 2.4GHz 802.11n with 20Mhz channel

any ideas?

```
void init_udp_send_socket(char*server_ip, int server_port) {

    if ( (server_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to open socket");
        exit(2);
    }
 
    memset((char *) &base, 0, sizeof(base));
    base.sin_family = AF_INET;
    base.sin_port = htons(server_port);
     
    if (inet_aton(server_ip , &base.sin_addr) == 0) 
    {
        perror( "Bad base IP address\n");
        exit(1);
    }  
}


void send_udp_datagram(char* blob, int size) {
     printf("size is: %d\n", size);
     if (sendto(server_socket, blob, size , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &base, sock_struct_size)==-1)
        {
           perror( "Failed sending datagram\n");
        } 
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your timing/delay code is working the same on both platforms? Why not create a small test program that grabs the current time, loops a large number of times with the delay *only* (no network I/O), then grab the time at the end. Are they roughly the same?

Comment: I've fixed the title to make clear that you are not sending from a plain linux but from a linux inside windows (WSL) - which is very different in terms of performance. You'll find many reports on the internet about bad network performance on WSL.

Comment: what's `server_ip` set to?  note that broadcast addresses are a special case and cause the network to switch to a basic rate (around 1 megabit per second)

Comment: Steffen Ullrich - the performance were exactly the same while running the program on an Intel NUC linux system.

Comment: @SamMason we server ip is the ip of the ipad (192.168.1.229)

Comment: @Papino ok, so it's probably not due to broadcasts then.  I'd expect the network stack to buffer outbound packets; you could try passing `MSG_DONTWAIT` and checking for errors if you really just want to give up immediately